# apt-get install overwrite ruby on docker of ubuntu14.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, dockerfile, apt

I do some test in the docker which use clean ubuntu14.04.
I use the below code to install ruby2.0 in the dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install \
    ruby2.0 \
    ruby2.0-dev
```

Then i enter the docker.
The issue occur:
when i use

```
apt-get install ruby2.0
```

there is no question.
when i use

```
apt-get install ruby
```

after apt-get update, apt will find ruby1.9 to install and overwrite the link(/usr/bin/ruby), which means the default ruby version is 1.9 now.

For further development, i can not specify version. And also, i need to let this operation run well at ubuntu14.04 even i know it can pass at ubuntu16.
How can i fix this issue?

And is the apt source in the docker different from ubuntu14.04?

Comment: Why don't you use `ruby`'s official docker image?

Answer (score 0):

The `apt-add-repository` doesn't exist. And the official ubuntu:14.04 image doesn't include `add-apt-repository` by default. You need to install it with

```
apt-get update && apt-get install software-properties-common
```

After this, you can install your ruby by,

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
apt-get update && apt-get -y install ruby2.0 ruby2.0-dev
```

I am not sure how your Dockerfile can run without error. But there a tip for you to write a Dockerfile. Always run the command in the container first, before write it to the Dockerfile.